# Small doubt regarding Cookies

Tags: seo

I have a website and for internal page I have take keyword as hyderabad and I kept this keyword hyderabad in cookies so that when we surf the subcategories we would get that page from the cookies... So my doubt is when crawler visits the subcategory page then does it identifies cookies and can identify the keyword....if yes how...

Answer (score 2):

It is always best to assume they're not using cookies. Plus, real users themselves can disable cookie if they don't find your site to be trusted enough.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be better to use the keyword as a SESSION variable instead of a cookie.